# Delete HTML code and leave only the content? (html2text error)

Tags: python, html, csv

I have a csv file from scraped data that is in HTML format for prices. I would like to only keep the number and the euro sign, and I am trying to use html2text to do this. (If you have a better alternative, please say so!). One cell in the csv looks like this for example:

```
<p class="price ">

        €1,750 

        <span class="type">
                            /month
                    </span>
        <span class="inclusive">
                    (ex.)
                </span>

    </p>
```

I thought about using unescape from html2text but I am getting an import error for unescape. This is the code I would use:

```
import pandas as pd
import html2text
from html2text import unescape 

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

print(df.head())

df.Price = df.Price.apply(unescape, unicode_snob=True)
```

but it gives me the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'unescape' from 'html2text' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/html2text/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Can you please share the full code? There is not mention of `html2text` in your post.

Comment: oh sorry, it's just the imports and I use unescape inside the .apply

Comment: Thanks for updating the question! No worries, I'll proceed with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your prices are stored in `prices.html` in the format you described, you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to solve your problem. It has functions dedicating to extracting data from HTML.

You can install it by running `pip install bs4`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

prices = []
with open("prices.html") as prices_file:
    # Create a soup based on the file
    soup = BeautifulSoup(prices_file, "html.parser")

    # Find all <p> tags that have the "class" set as "price"
    price_html_tags = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class": "price"})

    # Iterate over the <p> tags, extract their text and strip the whitespace
    prices = [tag.find(text=True).strip() for tag in price_html_tags]

print(prices)
```